# slider HTML : align text and button in middle slider bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

in below code i want to align button,logo and text in center of images slider in bootstrap4 but here in my code it's not showing same on all devices plus i need to change css on every screen and this is a bad way i think... is there a better way to do this ?
thanks in advance

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 18%;
}

@media (min-width:320px) {
  .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 139px;
    left: 18%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 250px;
    left: 18%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:801px) {
  .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 280px;
    left: 18%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main">

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 " src="assets/images/dgWebsiteImages-25.jpg" alt="First Image">

        <div class="carousel-caption ">

          <img class="" src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fimages%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw2OejUw2y467GfAvPkIg7bK&ust=1667036104481000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjRxqFwoTCMCZ9srPgvsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;"
            alt="First Image">
          <div class="textslider">
            <h2>text text text text text text</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="wrapper">

            <a class="ripple rbutton" href="https://">Visit Website</a>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
<div
      id="carouselExampleIndicators"
      class="carousel slide"
      data-ride="carousel"
    >
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li
          data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-slide-to="0"
          class="active"
        ></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img
            class="d-block w-100"
            src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_184273a4147%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_184273a4147%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.9140625%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
            alt="First slide"
          />
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <img
              class=""
              src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fimages%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw2OejUw2y467GfAvPkIg7bK&ust=1667036104481000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjRxqFwoTCMCZ9srPgvsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"
              style="background-repeat: no-repeat"
              alt="First Image"
            />
            <div class="textslider">
              <h2>text text text text text text</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <a class="ripple rbutton" href="https://">Visit Website</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            class="d-block w-100"
            src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_184273a4148%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_184273a4148%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
            alt="Second slide"
          />
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <img
              class=""
              src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fimages%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw2OejUw2y467GfAvPkIg7bK&ust=1667036104481000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjRxqFwoTCMCZ9srPgvsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"
              style="background-repeat: no-repeat"
              alt="First Image"
            />
            <div class="textslider">
              <h2>text text text text text text</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <a class="ripple rbutton" href="https://">Visit Website</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            class="d-block w-100"
            src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_184273a4148%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_184273a4148%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22276.9921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
            alt="Third slide"
          />
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <img
              class=""
              src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fimages%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw2OejUw2y467GfAvPkIg7bK&ust=1667036104481000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjRxqFwoTCMCZ9srPgvsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"
              style="background-repeat: no-repeat"
              alt="First Image"
            />
            <div class="textslider">
              <h2>text text text text text text</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <a class="ripple rbutton" href="https://">Visit Website</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Just use this css

```
div.carousel-caption {
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: auto;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          }
```